# The Rocky Side of the World Without Oil

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, geology

Lately, there has been speculation of what would happen if all the untapped oil, by the handwaving powers of the gods of television and money, disappear overnight.  It has been explained, in varying degrees of detail, how this loss would affect life culturally, technologically and environmentally.  Yet one equally important angle is missing, just what is that angle?  I wonder...

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Of course!  The GEOLOGICAL angle!

This is an awfully big deal because, as these images show, oil is not a surface occurrence.  The oil layer is vertically surrounded, both up and down, by rocks.  If all the untapped oil on Earth just disappeared, the reservoirs now become empty gaps.  Should that ever happen, would the rocks at the top of the reservoirs collapse, causing the surface to fall down?

Comment: VERY relevant https://what-if.xkcd.com/6/

Comment: @Aify, I'd give my left eye to see that glass hit the ceiling, I'm just sayin', and it probably means if there's enough oil  the core of the earth would explode while the mantle hurtles into space in a daring remake of *Space 1999.*

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on how this "sudden disappear" is implemented: with or without substitution.

**With substitution**

Oil is replaced by something else, be it water or rock. No big deal, as there is no gap to be filled.

**Without substitution**

In this case you are right, there is gap. But mind that an oil layer is hardly an underground lake, it is more of a soaked sponge, the sponge being rock. Nevertheless the sudden lack of some of the filler will trigger readjustments in the ground. If the spongy gaps are larger than the surrounding ground can sustain, there would be a collapse, resulting in an earthquake.

If instead the spongy gap can be sustained by the surrounding ground, it will probably be filled by water and then, over geological times, by minerals carried by the water.

Comment: Can you give me an example on what you mean by "larger than the surrounding ground can sustain"?